# How to call JS to click a table element

Tags: javascript

Assume I get a table element with ID="emTab", how do I call JS to click it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>document.getElementById("emTab").onclick = function() {
        // your code goes here
    };</strike>

See **[element.onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick)**

To trigger click event

```
document.getElementById("emTab").click();
```

See **[element.click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click)**

> The click method is intended to be
>   used with INPUT elements of type
>   button, checkbox, radio, reset or
>   submit. Gecko does not implement the
>   click method on other elements that
>   might be expected to respond to
>   mouse–clicks such as links (A
>   elements), nor will it necessarily
>   fire the click event of other
>   elements.
>
> Non–Gecko DOMs may behave differently.
>
> When a click is used with elements
>   that support it (e.g. one of the INPUT
>   types listed above), it also fires the
>   element's click event which will
>   bubble up to elements higher up the
>   document tree (or event chain) and
>   fire their click events too. However,
>   bubbling of a click event will not
>   cause an A element to initiate
>   navigation as if a real mouse-click
>   had been received.

***Cross browser way***

If you can use jQuery then it would be

```
$("#emTab").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Hi, I want to use JS to trigger a click event, not the handler.

Comment: document.getElementById("emTab").click();.. does it works in FF??

Answer (score 1):

Firing events cross-browser - http://jehiah.cz/archive/firing-javascript-events-properly

Answer (score 0):

its simple using JQuery
$('#emTab').click(functionToCall);

while in JS
document.getElementById('emTab').onclick = function() {};

for details on DOM events:
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents